# Get a Table's Character Set

Tags: mysql, information-schema

In MySQL, I can get a table's name, engine and collation like so:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, ENGINE, TABLE_COLLATION
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name';
```

But how how do I get a table's character set, not just collation? Is it possible to get it from information_schema.tables?

Comment: Are you referring to DESCRIBE `table_name`?

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't show the char set. Is there a way to get it using SELECT?

Answer (score 1):

Each collation is used for only one character set, so it's not necessary to record the character set in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. The table collation is enough to indicate both the collation and the character set unambiguously.

You can check INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY to get the mapping from a given collation to its character set.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S WHERE schema_name = "DBNAME";
```

Comment: DESCRIBE 'tbl_name'; doesn't show a table's character set. I was thinking more of using a SELECT statement to get it.

Comment: That does get the character set, but it's for the whole database. Any way to do it like but just for a table?